# Promise doesn't seem to be resolved with await

Tags: javascript

I have found something interesting while playing with Promises and awaits:

```js
function returnPromise() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('result of promise');
    }, 1000);
  });
}


async function sth() {
  let result = await returnPromise();
  console.log('result: ', result);
  console.log('flag 1');
}

sth();
```

In this first example, the result of the promise prints out correctly. However, consider the second example:

```js
function returnPromise() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('result of promise');
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function sth2() {
  let result = returnPromise();
  await result;
  console.log('result: ', result);
  console.log('flag 1');
}

sth2();
```

Here, the result is {} (which I think means the Promise is still pending). This doesn't make sense to me because I thought the line 'await result' was supposed to block till the Promise resolved.

My question is:

1. Is this expected behavior? If it is, what is the logic behind it?
2. If this isn't what's expected, why is this happening?

Thank you.

Comment: `await result;` - you're throwing away the resolved value of the promise held in `result` - since that is what is being returned by the function .... `let x = await result;` and ... you're not throwing away the resolved value

Comment: Before “playing” I recommend you to read a book so you can understand how it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought the line 'await result' was supposed to block till the Promise resolved.

Well, it blocks further execution of *that async function* - but yes.

But the `result` is still a Promise.

`await` will take the thenable on its right side, wait for it to finish, and extract the resolve value from it. But the thenable will *remain a thenable* - it doesn't change the Promise itself (it doesn't change the Promise expression into the value it resolves to).

```
await someThenable
```

extracts the resolve value from `someThenable`, but `someThenable` remains a thenable - logging `someThenable`, whether before or after the `await`, will still log the thenable, and not the resolve value.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let result = returnPromise();
```

This line sets the value of `result` to be a *reference* to the `Promise` object. It does not automagically change to be the result of the `await`ed promise whenever you call `await` on it later on.

You can tell by the fact that there's still a waiting period that the `await` keyword is working. However, you're throwing away the result value.

`await` will give you and rvalue that you can assign to a variable:

```js
let actualResult = await result;
// or
result = await result; // but you shouldn't do this
```